# How to track physical drives to server LUNs & mount points

Tags: storage-area-network, iscsi, cifs, documentation, hp-smart-array

I need to document which physical drives each server depends on ( SAN,  on an external array, iSCSI etc). Since this potentially a many-many relationship, with dependencies, finding a usable solution is a small challenge.

> What tools (or Excel tricks) do you use to document the dependencies mentioned above?

Comment: What's your environment? SAN? Are you using virtualization?

Comment: We have VMWare using a SAN, and Exchange using either an HP array, or also the SAN

Comment: A little more elaboration would help. Are the guests directly logging into the SAN using something like iSCSI or is Vmware managing the SAN for you and you're merely carving storage out for the guests to use?

Comment: I'm looking for general guidance for a variety of scenarios... examples would be appreciated.  Bottom line; I want to learn from other's organisational and storage management techniques.  Simply understanding the column headers (in an Excel doc) would assist in structuring my thoughts, inventory, and configuration

Answer (score 0):

If your familiar with Perl, take a look a [VMWare's Perl SDK](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/viperltoolkit/).  You can use it to pull most details, including mount/drive/lun information.  If you have vcenter, you can connect to it instead of connecting to your individual servers.